# Yii: How to force CGridview to load data via AJAX only?

Tags: yii

Is there a way to make a CGridView *Not* load data on the initial rendering of the view it lives on, and instead make it load the first page with a subsequent AJAX request after the initial page load?

This is mostly for performance optimization. There is a data model that is rather slow behind that CGridView, and I would like to be able to have the page load in a snappy way, then have the data load up a few seconds later with an AJAX request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify the action as follows:

```
public function actionIndex() {
  $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User'); // The dataprovider your grid uses
  if (!$this->isAjaxRequest()) {
    $dataProvider->criteria->addCondition('1 = 0'); // You could also use 0, but I think this is more clear
  }

  [...]
}
```

And then in your view in the javascript section:

```
$(function() { // If you are using jQuery this is executed when the page is loaded
  $.fn.yiiGridView.update("{id-of-your-grid-view}");
});
```

Comment: isAjaxRequest() is not a method of Controller. It is a property of CHttpRequest. So, while you can check for ajax request, e.g., if (!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)... and then proceed with this suggested solution by adding the condition and the update function, this doesn't actually work. The grid doesn't load at all. I'll come back and post a working solution once I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Brewer Gorge was very close, and thanks to his suggested answer, it put me on the right track. This works:

```
// Controller, after creating $dataProvider, before calling $this->render...
if (!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest) {
    $dataProvider->criteria->addCondition('1 = 0');
}

// View
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#id-of-grid').yiiGridView('update');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write your code in controller like this:

```
$model= new Data('search');
$model->unsetAttributes();

if(isset($_GET['Data']))
   $model->attributes = $_GET['Data'];

if (!Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
   $data->id=0; //or something that sure model return empty
```